# How to escape apostrophe when displaying inside a ASP.NET label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following function which truncates a SQL Server `varchar` column and adds it to a string:

```
public void Pp()
{
    strSql = @""; //query
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gstr))
    {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn);

            myDataSet = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(myDataSet);

            string specific = "";
            string generic = "";
            string strTemp = "";

            foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (r["MessageText"].ToString().Length <= 65)
                {
                    strTemp = r["MessageText"].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    strTemp = TruncateLongString(r["MessageText"].ToString(), 65);
                }
                specific += "</b><span class='hoverText' title='" + r["MessageText"] + "'>" + strTemp + "...</span>";
                strTemp = "";
            }

            lblMessage.Text = "<b>SPECIFIC MESSAGES:</b> <br />" + specific;
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
        }
    }
}
public string TruncateLongString(string str, int maxLength)
{
    return str.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
```

If the `r["MessageText"]` contains an appostrophe, it cuts off anything after it. (full text: `no way no way HERE we go again but this is not working. Is it? or Is it not? I can't be too sure though. Can someone please check.`)

Here is an example of a live preview (the `title` is shown but gets cut off because of the apostrophe):

[image]

Here is the source (the apostrophe is shown in the purple box. Also the color coding gets out of whack due to the apostrophe, which means the code is not correct):

[image]

How can I ensure it doesn't escape any escape characters, e.g. `'`, `/`, `\`.

Comment: Have you tried `&apos;`? For example `can&apos;t`

Comment: Your database code is too heavy and suboptimal. You don't need to read everything into a `DataTable`, consider calling `ExecuteReader` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode the HTML first.

Call `this.Server.HtmlEncode( str )`. This will also protect against other special characters like `&` and `<`.

That said, you're using single-quotes for attribute delimiters but `HtmlEncode` only encodes double-quotes, so you need to change your code to this:

```
specific = String.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"</b><span class=""hoverText"" title=""" + this.Server.HtmlEncode( r["MessageText"] ) + """>" + strTemp + @"...</span>";
```

Comment: I just needed `this.Server.HtmlEncode()` and it fixed it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

.Replace(" ' ", "\\' "); You will probably want to do the same with double quote as well.